# How to find the interior of a subset in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, multivariable-calculus

How can I determine the interior $\text{Int}A$ of $$A:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid y^2 + z^2 \leq 1 \text{ and } 0 \leq x < 1 \}\;\;\;\;?$$ I am thinking about half a cylindrical, but I am not sure!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Consider a point $(x,y,z)\in A$ with $y^2+z^2<1$ and $x>0$. Can you find $r>0$ for which the sphere centred at $(x,y,z)$ of radius $r$ is contained in $A$?

Now consider $(x,y,z)\in A$ with either $x=0$ or $y^2+z^2=1$, and let $r>0$. Is the sphere centred at $(x,y,z)$ of radius $r$ contained in $A$?

Looking at the definition of the interior of a subset, you should be able to work out which of the above describe the interior points of $A$ (and therefore what $\text{Int}(A)$ is). It is what you might expect it to be based on geometric intuition.

Comment: For your first question it's a YES! since r can be y+x / 2 and for the second question i must say NO! there is no such r. but how can i write the int(A)?
like $y^2 + z^2 < 1$ and x between 0 and 1?

Comment: @RoozbehRanjbar I've updated my answer in light of your comment. Not sure where you got that value of $r$ from, but any $r<\min\{x,1-x,1-y^2-z^2\}$ should do

Comment: sorry i meant $r = ( y + z ) / 2$, but thats not good enough if you choose your point very close to where $x = 0$. Yours is clear though. Thanks in advance.